# For each Array in Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, express

I am currently developing an application using node.js, Express and JS/Jquery.

I have run into an issue where I want to append elements to a webpage based on how many arrays are contained within a MD array.

So if there is 6 Arrays only ever append for each array, then change how it looks based on a set of requirements I have set.

But the appending elements is all over the place and am getting replicated values on the web page where I only want them once.

**For example:**

```
[ [ '477', 'Test User', '487', 'online', 'ANSWER' ],
  [ '487', 'Test User', '477', 'online', 'ANSWER' ],
  [ '488', 'Test User', '490', 'online', 'ANSWER' ],
  [ '490', 'Test User', '488', 'online', 'ANSWER' ] ]
```

So there are 4 arrays in the MD array, so all I want to have on my web page is 477, 487, 488 & 490 once hence why am trying to do it per array.

But it replicates them all so I thought a for each might be the best option but am having trouble getting it to work for each array.

I have had a look at a couple of other questions in regards to this but have not been able to get anything successful working accordingly.

**Current Code**

```
socket.on("eventsRegister", function (regisdata) {
    for(var i in regisdata)
    {
                         $presence.append('<div class="col-md-2 md tile">\
                                <h6>\
                                    <b>'+ regisdata[i][0] +'</b>\
                                    </h6>\
                                    </div>');
    if (regisdata[i][0] && regisdata[i][3] === "online") {
        $("div[class*='tile']:not(.answer .noanswer .ring .hangup):contains('" + regisdata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("ring").css("background-color", "#78ff4d").html("<h6><img  src='../images/online.png'> <b>" + regisdata[i][0] + "</b></h6><p></p>");
    } else if (regisdata[i][0] && regisdata[i][3] === "offline") {
        $("div[class*='tile']:not(.answer .noanswer .ring .hangup):contains('" + regisdata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("ring").css("background-color", "white").html("<h6><img  src='../images/offline.png'> <b>" + regisdata[i][0] + "</b></h6><p></p>");
    }
}
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or assist in the matter?

EDIT(Updated)

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure what exactly do you want, but here goes nothing:

```
for(var key in MDarray)
{
    var subarray = MDarray[key];

    // Now subarray = [ '477', 'Test User', '487', 'online', 'ANSWER' ]
    // And subarray[0] = '477'

    // To skip some array inside the MDarray, you can do
    // if(subarray[0] === '477') { continue; } for example

    // You can also loop the subarray with 
    // for(var key2 in subarray) { var subarrval = subarray[key]; }
}
```

Simplified:

```
for(var key in MDarray)
{
    var online = MDarray[key][3];
    // append online status code here
}
```

Your full code should look something like this:

```
socket.on("eventsRegister", function (regisdata) 
{
    for(var key in regisdata)
    {
        var data = regisdata[key];
        var onlinestatus = data[3];

        // append onlinestatus somehow
    }
});
```

Comment: In short if I have 4 arrays in a MD array I only want to append 4 times. That is literally all I need

Comment: I made simplified version in my answer. This gets the 'online' status of each sub-array, so that if you console.log(online) in the loop, it would say 'online' 4 times or how many arrays there are in the MDarray.

Comment: Still replicating values with the suggested solution sadly.

Comment: @Studento919 This fiddle works: https://jsfiddle.net/019zeaxh/1/ The word 'online' appended 4 times, which is the amount of arrays in the array. I also added how your full code should look in my answer.

Comment: Still appending more than what I want, I i refresh the page it works the amount is correct but doing it in real time its still replicating ;/ Updated my question so you can see what I have. That works in the updated code its still just replicated values.

Comment: "eventsRegister" must be getting fired more than 1 time then, as the loop cannot possibly append multiple times as far as I know. Try console logging in the eventsRegister callback function and see if it logs something multiple times.

Comment: Yeah it gets fired every time, an event gets caught which i believe is whats causing the replicated values :( The code itself you provided is correct

Comment: Well I cannot help you with that, as I do not know how or when the event gets fired.

Comment: Its something that cant be avoided I thought doing what you suggested but it doesnt, I did find a work around by simply $('.tile').remove(); and removing everything and it works...but it affects a single function in regards to a call hanging up. ill give the credit due :) cheers for taking the time to assist